# Ожидание загрузки множества json'ов

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Приветствую. В проекте используется несколько json файлов с данными, и мне необходима загрузка всех файлов. Но столкнулся с трудностью: в jQuery событие загрузки работает отдельно для каждого файла:

```
var jdata = $.getJSON('/assets/json/txg_templates.json', function() {
    $jdataSuccess = true;
});
var boxSizing = $.getJSON('/assets/json/txg_resize.json', function() {
    $boxSizingSuccess = true;
});
```

Пробовал сделать цикл проверки по значениям булевых переменных из примера, но такой способ по непонятной мне причине работает нестабильно. Есть какой-то другой способ загружать json-ы массово с событием завершения загрузки?

Comment: "работает нестабильно"?

Comment: @Igor Не загружает json и булева остается в false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
$.when(jdata, boxSizing).done(function(){
  console.log($jdataSuccess && $boxSizingSuccess);
});)
```